# How to check the text is a valid date with specfic date format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have read lots of website for date checking. However, some of those are useless because I want to set the date format to `dd/MM/yyyy`.

```
var result = new Date(input);
if (result == 'Invalid Date') {
    return false;
```

For the code above,

- it is still valid if i enter '60/09/02016'.
- it return MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: I tried new Date(''60/09/02016'') it is also invalid

Comment: You can simply use moment.js. It will allow you check valid date in any format you want

Comment: You need to call result.toString() in your if condition. Then it will return "Invalid Date" if date is not valid

Comment: @user3273700 it return "2020-12-05T16:00:00.000Z" if i enter Date(''60/09/02016'')

Comment: @user3273700 i cannot use moment.js because the client only allows me to use jQuery for javascript library :( Therefor, i have no idea how to do this.(I know how to use moment.js)

Comment: @kingyau what's the client's objection to momentJS? If you explain it will save you time to solve a problem it's hard to see the problem, especially if jQuery is already permitted. Otherwise you have to re-invent the wheel...and it's a very complicated wheel.

Comment: @ADyson—it's a very simple wheel. Parsing and validating the OP format is 3 lines of code.

Comment: @RobG even ensuring that the date actually exists (e.g. extra days in leap years and all that?) And I was referring to date parsing in general really. I'm sure Moment wouldn't be so popular if anyone could knock it together in 3 lines

Comment: @RobG but if you can do all that in 3 lines then all power to you, I'll be duly impressed

Comment: @ADyson—for sure, a general parser is a bit more work (and a good exercise). There are plenty of small libraries that do parsing very well, so no point in reinventing that wheel. But for a single format, it's quite easy. In modern browsers, the OP format can be validated with `new Date(s.split(/\D/).reverse().join('-')) != 'Invalid Date'`. But I wouldn't suggest actually doing that (since it relies on unreliable parsing and possibly confusing implicit conversion of Date object to string primitive). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use the moment.js (http://www.momentjs.com) library in your code, then it's very simple:

```
var input = '60/09/2016';
var dt = moment(input,'DD/MM/YYYY');
alert(dt.isValid()); //returns true or false depending on whether the date is valid and in the correct format
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moment to validate date. Follow the below code may be its is useful for you !

```
     var moment = require('moment')
     var m = moment('2015-11-32', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
     console.log(m.isValid()) // false
```

For Browser you can use cdn or download js from moment site

```
   <script src="moment.js"></script>
   <script>
     var m = moment('2015-11-32', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
     console.log(m.isValid()) // false
  </script>
```

**Refer** : http://momentjs.com

**JS_Link** : http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js

*download moment.js and refer in your project.*

Comment: "require" will only work on nodeJS, not in the browser. OP didn't specify either way. And also the date format isn't the one asked for by the OP. Otherwise the example is ok.

Comment: You can use the same in browser, Follow the updated answer

Comment: ok that's more comprehensive - thanks

Comment: If there is any struggle it working or not let me know its help ful for you

Comment: no it's fine, I know how to use it (see my answer below) just wanted to clarify for OP the difference between node and browser references to the library

Comment: I did't get you. Can you explain in detail .What you need to know

Comment: _I_ don't need to know anything. I wanted you to clarify the question for the _OP's_ benefit, which you have done, and I have thanked you for already. I'm not really sure why we are still talking about this :-)

Comment: What i am thinking na you expect something to know. So that only i am asking .Sorry for that . For your clarification that is **OP** difference between that two is not so much difference both are giving same response the place of compile is only differ.

Comment: Answers should explain the OPs issue and why your answer fixes it. Answers should not depend on libraries that are not tagged or asked for in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Use `datepicker` then and restrict the user to input any characters on it.

Comment: This is not an answer, it's barely a comment.

Comment: sorry cuz i can't comment for now.